# Is there a class such as Duration but for digital information measures (i.e. Kilobytes, Megabytes, etc.) in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin's stdlib since version 1.3 has added the `Duration` class (albeit in experimental status so far, but nevertheless) which allows to represent duration between two instants in time, and to format them in nice human-readable form using the included `toString()` function/method.

The question is, does anybody know about any similar class (either 'standard' or otherwise) which would allow to represent sizes of digital information, in bytes, and also to format them in a nice human-readable form? So, for example, size of `7_340_032` bytes would be printed as `7 MBytes` or `7 MB` or even `7M`, or something similar.

Just to be clear, I am not looking to *always* format *all* sizes as megabytes. What I would like to have, is for the class to 'detect' the most suitable unit for the given size at hand, just like the aforementioned `Duration` class does.

Comment: Wouldn't the 'most suitable' unit, like the most suitable precision, vary too much depending on the circumstances?  Also, since this is simply an integer with no timezones or calendars to confuse things, does it justify a separate type?

Comment: @gidds it would, but having something ready that is 'good enough' for most cases would certainly be nicer than having to code something like that from scratch. Time durations also do not have time zones or calendars, BTW. Just look at the implementation of that class in stdlib to know what I am talking about.